# ORACLE SQL - SUM value multiplied by number of records

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I've read through other postings with this problem, and have tried their solutions, but have not made any headway. I would be grateful for any help you could provide.

I have three instances of the same table, pulling different OTH_PAY values from the same field, dependent upon the ERNCD entry. In the case where a single ERNCD has mutliple OTH_PAY entries on the same EFFDT, the SUM value is multiplied by the number of entries.

I need to get the SUM total for each ERNCD on each EFFDT.

```
SELECT F1.EMPLID, 
SUM(F1.OTH_PAY)"004", 
 SUM(F2.OTH_PAY)"005",
SUM(F3.OTH_PAY)"RAD"
FROM PAY_DATA F1, PAY_DATA F2, PAY_DATA F3
WHERE F1.EMPLID = F2.EMPLID
  AND F1.EMPL_RCD = F2.EMPL_RCD
  AND F1.EMPLID = F3.EMPLID
  AND F1.EMPL_RCD = F3.EMPL_RCD
  AND F1.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(F1_ED.EFFDT) FROM PAY_DATA F1_ED
                  WHERE F1.EMPLID = F1_ED.EMPLID
                    AND F1.EMPL_RCD = F1_ED.EMPL_RCD)
  AND F2.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(F2_ED.EFFDT) FROM PAY_DATA F2_ED
                  WHERE F2.EMPLID = F2_ED.EMPLID
                    AND F2.EMPL_RCD = F2_ED.EMPL_RCD)
  AND F3.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(F3_ED.EFFDT) FROM PAY_DATA F3_ED
                  WHERE F3.EMPLID = F3_ED.EMPLID
                    AND F3.EMPL_RCD = F3_ED.EMPL_RCD)
  AND F1.ERNCD = '004'
  AND F2.ERNCD = '005'
  AND F3.ERNCD = 'RAD'
  AND F1.EMPLID = '12345678'
GROUP BY F1.EMPLID
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to use conditional aggregation.  But, you also have a condition on the date, so that requires some cleverness -- I mean, the use of analytic functions:

```
select emplid,
       sum(case when erncd = '004' then oth_pay end) as op_004,
       sum(case when erncd = '005' then oth_pay end) as op_005,
       sum(case when erncd = 'RAD' then oth_pay end) as op_rad
from (select pd.*,
             rank() over (partition by emplid, empl_rcd, erncd order by effdt desc) as seqnum
      from pay_data pd
     ) pd
where seqnum = 1
group by emplid;
```

Comment: I was also thinking along this lines, however, I don't think you want `row_number` in this case, he's using the latest EFFDT to retrieve all rows that match that date. It might be more than 1 row. Probably want `FIRST_VALUE(EFFDT) over (partition by ..... order by effdt desc` and then instead of `where seqnum = 1`, do `effdt = seqnum` ;)   ??? or something along that lines ?

Comment: This is giving me data from the most recent record, but not the SUM of all values for a specific ERNCD on a specific EFFDT.

Comment: @Ditto . . . I think `rank()` or `dense_rank()` work for this.

Comment: @Gordon agreed - that should work as well depending on OPs specific needs